# error C2296: '*' : illegal, left operand has type '__int64 *'|

Tags: c++

Following code produces the error:

```
error C2296: '*' : illegal, left operand has type '__int64 *'|
```

Error line (<------)

```
DWORD increasefactor = 1;

__int64 initialtime64 = 0;
__int64 initialoffset64 = 0;

...

BOOL WINAPI QueryPerformanceCounter_Detour(__int64 *lp)
{
    BOOL ret = QueryPerformanceCounter_Trampoline(lp);
    lp = ((lp-initialtime64)*increasefactor)+initialoffset64;   // <------
    return ret;
}
```

Where is my fault?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think you wanted `(lp-initialtime64)`.

Comment: i need.. i have to substract the initial value (which is set in another procedure) from the actual one.

Comment: Yeah, and right now you're subtracting something from an address to get another address, then trying to multiply that address by something, which makes no sense. Is there any specific reason why `lp` is a pointer?

Comment: The MSDN: BOOL WINAPI QueryPerformanceCounter(
  _Out_  LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount
);

Comment: Might as well use a reference then, but with a pointer, you have to dereference it to get the value.

Comment: so i need to change (lp-initialtime64) to (*lp-initialtime64) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lp` is a pointer to an `__int64`, not an actual `__int64`. The expression

```
lp = ((lp-initialtime64)*increasefactor)+initialoffset64;
```

attempts to assign an integer to a pointer to an integer, not to mention the fact that you are subtracting from that same pointer later in the same line.

You need to dereference the pointer with the `*` operator to get at the value pointed to by `lp`.

```
*lp = ((*lp-initialtime64)*increasefactor)+initialoffset64;
```

You should probably also read up on pointers in C++/C.

Comment: That solved it :D thanks a lot. I'm not that firm with c++ since i usually use Delphi.. :(

Comment: No problem. Pointers are crucial to working with C++/C, tho, so I really suggest checking them out.